# Ajax Paging Mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

I need help.
I'm doing a simple blog using MVC 4.

**Edit3**: In general, the concept is as follows: on the left is a navigation bar with the categories, on the right posts with ajax paging. When you click on the concrete post, we turn to the page with the details of post.

I have a layout:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="sidebar-nav-fixed fill">
                @Html.Action("GetCategories","Navigation")
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-nav-fixed-stuck-left fill white">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <div class="content-area">
                                @RenderBody()
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I return from controller list of posts with paging. Pager creates ajax links to the controller:

```
<a data-ajax=\"true\" data-ajax-method=\"GET\" data-ajax-mode=\"replace\" href=\"{0}\" data-page=\"{1}\">{2}</a>
```

If I return a partial view without layout, it is rendered only partial view, but ajax paging works. If I return a partial view with layout, it is rendered perfectly, ajax query works and controller return partial view,but paging doesn't work.

View

```
@model PagingListViewModel<PostViewModel>

@*@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}*@

@foreach (var post in Model.Items)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(_ => post,"Post")
}

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PageInfo)
```

Edit: I use custom pager. It generates ajax links,if flag "isAjax" is true.
This is a method that generates a link for each page

```
private string GeneratePageLink(string linkText, int pageNumber)
        {
            var pageLinkValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(linkWithoutPageValuesDictionary);
            pageLinkValueDictionary[Page] = pageNumber;

            var contextQueryString = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
            foreach (string queryStrings in contextQueryString)
            {
                if (queryStrings.Equals(Page, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    pageLinkValueDictionary.ContainsKey(queryStrings))
                    continue;

                pageLinkValueDictionary.Add(queryStrings, contextQueryString[queryStrings]);
            }

            var virtualPath = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, pageLinkValueDictionary) == null
                                  ? string.Empty
                                  : RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, pageLinkValueDictionary)
                                              .VirtualPath;

            return string.Format(
                isAjax
                    ? "<li><a data-ajax=\"true\" data-ajax-method=\"GET\" data-ajax-mode=\"replace\" href=\"{0}\" data-page=\"{1}\">{2}</a></li>"
                    : "<li><a href=\"{0}\" data-page=\"{1}\">{2}</a></li>",
                virtualPath, pageNumber, linkText
                );
        }
```

Edit2:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Posts(int? page)
{
... query to database
return AjaxPagingList<Post, PostViewModel>(posts, "PostsList")
}

 protected ActionResult AjaxPagingList<TItem, TModel>(IEnumerable<TItem> itemsObjects, string view)
            where TItem : class, where TModel: class
        {
            var items = AutoMappingProvider.MapToList<TItem>(itemsObjects);

            var catalogViewModel = new PagingListViewModel<TModel>
            {
               ....
            }

            return PartialView(view, catalogViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Are you returning the full view on the initial page request and the partial for the ajax pager requests?

Comment: Can you show the relevant javascript that is handling the ajax posts?

Comment: I use custom pager. It generates ajax links,if flag "isAjax" is true.

Comment: The first call of the controller method isn't ajax, the other calls are ajax - through links formed pager. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also show the controller action(s) that is/are handling these requests?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I changed a partial view:

```
@model PagingListViewModel<PostViewModel>

@{
    Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@foreach (var post in Model.Items)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(_ => post,"Post")
}

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PageInfo)
```

And added attribute to a link data-ajax-update="...".